# If $q(t)\underset{t\to +\infty}{\to}1$ then number of zeros of solution of $x^{''}+q(t)x=0$ verify $N(t)\underset{t\to +\infty}{\sim}\frac{t}{\pi}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let  $q:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous function such that $q(t)\underset{t\to +\infty}{\to}1$. We consider $\phi$ solution of differential equation : $x^{''}+q(t)x=0$ and  $N(t)$ is the number of zeros of $\phi$ over $[0,t]$. Show that $$N(t)\underset{t\to +\infty}{\sim}\frac{t}{\pi}$$
I thought about using Sturm's theorem but I don't know how. An idea please. Thancks.

Comment: Control $q$ in a neighbourhood of $+\infty$ and apply Sturm.

Comment: I have already tried to say that there exists $M>0$  such that for all $t\geq M$ we have: $$\frac {1}{2}\leq q (t) \leq\frac {3}{2}$$
but I do not know if it will help me. Could you give me your answer?